# Bootstrap navbar - wrap nav-item to the next row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Currently I try to build a Navbar that is responsive. I use Bootstrap for my css. What I want is that: On a small viewport all links but the Navbar-brand is listed within one row. The Navbar on a large viewport looks like this (as expected):
[image]

But when I shrink the viewport the Navbar looks like this:
[image]

I already managed some viewport configurations, that e.g the username is not displayed on a small viewport. The HTML looks as follows (Btw. I will only show some mocked nav-items, since this is not important for the question:

### HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark flex-column flex-md-row">
  <div class="navbar-nav flex-row">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2">
          <img src="assets/loading-skull.png" width="30px" height="auto">
          Scare-me.com
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Stories</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="mx-auto">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto hide-on-small-viewport" href="#">Show your threads!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Log In</a>
        </li>

        <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="btn mt-1 mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md3">Logout</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: So, what do you want when the window shrink? Move it into two rows and `Stories` in the second line?

Comment: So where will the "Show your threads!" go in small viewport? Is it hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit difficult to achieve what you want without drastically changing the whole html structure of your navbar. I am not sure if you are up for that. So I would suggest keeping  2 buttons for "Stories". Show one button in mobile view and the other in desktop view. This will ensure minimal regression impact to your html structure.

Button for desktop views

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-none d-md-block">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">Stories</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Button for mobile view

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-none d-md-block">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">Stories</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark flex-column flex-md-row">
  <div class="navbar-nav flex-row">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2">
          <img src="assets/loading-skull.png" width="30px" height="auto"> Scare-me.com
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-none d-md-block">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Stories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="mx-auto">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto hide-on-small-viewport" href="#">Show your threads!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-md-none">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Stories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Log In</a>
      </li>

      <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="btn mt-1 mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md3">Logout</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Good answer, Nandita!